# Using displays with Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino-uno, display

Does anybody know if there is any documentation available online on basic information about using displays with Arduino Uno? I've never used displays before and would very much appreciate some basic information on the different types etc..

Any information that can help me choose what display I want to buy for my next project will be helpful.

for ex: Right now I don't even know what a shield is in context to a display and whether or not I should look for one in my purchasing my display.

Comment: A shield is just an Arduino-shaped horse that holds electronics, and is not related to using a display per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Arduino website has a [list of LCD displays](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/LCD) and link with more information about each one. For controlling the display you may want to look at Arduino's [LiquidCrystal Library](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystal).

If you are looking for a step by step guide for using a lcd display with the Arduino, there is a [nice guide on Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-11-lcd-displays-1/).